# update-package : Failed to parse the input of Version parameter: highest to a valid Semantic version

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

I created a Nuget feed with multiple packages.
My solution uses various of those packages in different projects.
When I publish a new version of the feed I need to update the versions my project uses.

It is quite fiddly to use VS2017->Tools-> Manage Packages For Solution , so I want to use Package Manager Console

I set the Package source and the Default project in the Package Manager Console UI.

What command do I type ?

I tried

```
update-package mypackagename -Version highest
```

but I get

```
update-package : Failed to parse the input of Version parameter: highest to a valid Semantic version.
```

My versions a pre-release with version names generated from Azure Devops like

```
v2.0.0-Cl-201920226-04750
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> update-package : Failed to parse the input of Version parameter:
>   highest to a valid Semantic version

You should use the command line:

```
update-package mypackagename
```

Check more info [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package#parameters):

> **Version**: The version to use for the upgrade, **defaulting to the latest version**. In NuGet 3.0+, the version value must be one of
>   Lowest, Highest, HighestMinor, or HighestPatch (equivalent to -Safe).

So, if we do not  specify the package update version, Package Manager Console will update the latest version by default.

**Note:**

The options `Lowest`, `Highest`, `HighestMinor`, or `HighestPatch` is used for manage the Dependency Version for **NuGet CLI**. The description in the documentation may not be clear enough. You could use it in the Package Manager Console like:

```
update-package mypackagename -DependencyVersion highest
```

**Note2**:

If your package is pre-release, you could add the parameter `-IncludePrerelease` in the command line.

Hope this helps.