# Nuget command to replace existing references with nuget references?

Tags: nuget, xaf

In VS2017 I created a new Winforms project using the XAF Solutions Wizard ( Entity Framework Code - First)

The wizard adds references according to options I select.

Now I want to change all the packages to use my Nuget Feed for the Dev Express References.

[XAF does have Nuget packages](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T683784/xaf-nuget-packages)

Is there a Nuget command that I can use to do this automatically?

[Cross posted to Dev Express](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T723440/nuget-command-to-replace-existing-references-with-nuget-references)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975565/update-package-failed-to-parse-the-input-of-version-parameter-highest-to-a-va

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with Nugets unless you script your way out as we are doing in XAF community project [expandFramework](https://github.com/eXpandFramework/eXpand). For some cases it won't work, however for a similar case here is what we do.

1. Parse all your projects for References start with DevExpress and construct a list of assemblies
2. For all assemblies in the list add them to packages.config
3. For all assemblies use the [DevExpress.PackageContent](https://github.com/eXpandFramework/DevExpress.PackageContent) project to link to the containing the packages.

```
Get-DxNugets 18.2.6
```

4. Install the found packages from step 3

```
`Nuget  Install packageName -OutputFolder $commonOutputFolder
```

5. Update the DevExpress references HintPath to the packages installation folder.

```
Update-HintPath -OutputPath "$packageInstallationfolder" -SourcesPath $rootPath -filter "DevExpress*"
```

all powershell functions come from the [XpandPosh](https://github.com/eXpandFramework/XpandPosh/) project. There are many helpful methods there unfortunately no docs. But you can get [support](https://github.com/eXpandFramework/eXpand/issues)

Comment: Thanks, it will take me a while to investigate that. Also I am considering package references `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference`

Comment: many already published packages won't work with package reference due to compatibility issues.