# NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotChart.Win

Tags: nuget, xaf

I want to upgrade [my xaf General Ledger Project](https://github.com/kgreed/SBD.GeneralLedger) to use the latest version of XAF.

Looking at the module project I thought I would start by running the following in the Package Management Console

```
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.Core.All
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotChart.Win
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotChart
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotGrid
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotGrid.Win
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2.Win
update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2
```

However I get Errors as follows

```
PM> update-package DevExpress.ExpressApp.Core.All
No package updates are available from the current package source for project 'UnitTestProject1\SBD.GL.Module.Tests.csproj'.
Restoring packages for D:\dev\SBD.GeneralLedger\SBD.GL.Cli\SBD.GL.Cli.csproj...
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotChart.Win 18.2.5 requires DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotChart (= 18.2.5) but version DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotChart 18.2.6 was resolved.
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotGrid.Win 18.2.5 requires DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotGrid (= 18.2.5) but version DevExpress.ExpressApp.PivotGrid 18.2.6 was resolved.
NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2.Win 18.2.5 requires DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2 (= 18.2.5) but version DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2 18.2.6 was resolved.
```

Note that the Cli project does contain a reference to the Win project

And the Win project does reference dll's created by the Cli project.

Maybe that is the reason

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55132859/nuget-command-to-replace-existing-references-with-nuget-references